# downgrading rails project from 3.2.1 to 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

My first Rails project deploy, and I've run into an issue.
The project is Rails 3.2.1, Ruby 1.9.3
Yesterday, I was given the hosting access, and they're having Rails 2.3.3, Ruby 1.8.7

If I'll decide to still deploy the app there, what changes do I need to make to it?

Specifically, I'm interested in Gemfile changes.
Here's my current gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '2.3.3'#'3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'haml'

gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```

What do I need to change? How do I look-up all the required dependencies and gems versions for old Rails versions?

Comment: Though I can' give a direct reply, I suggest you to change Hosting. Hosting is so cheap comparing with code.

Comment: I would find another host, Rails 2.3.3 is over 4 years old. Not only are there numerous security patches since then, but your likely to find little to no support for gem versions that support that version of rails. The Gemfile will be the least of your worries.

Comment: is there any reason why you can't upgrade the server to rails 3?  if some other app is hosted on the server that uses ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2, i suggest you to install rvm/rbenv to manage the ruby versions so you can install 1.9.3 and deploy your app there.

Comment: i can only second the 3 other responses. ditch your host without a second thought.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I can't upgrade the server to rails 3 because the hosting company wouldn't give me the clearance needed. It's what they have installed. So I think, I'll try my luck with some other hosters. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downgrading from 3.x to 2.3 is the dumbest thing you can do in your case.
Install gems locally, or ask your hosting company support department — they have to help.

If you can't, save your time — use Heroku, OpenShift or any other hosting company.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm already looking for alternative hosting companies thanks to the responces to my question. Thanks again!